# how to use localhost in conjunction with retrofit for testing of android apps kotlin

Tags: php, android, kotlin, xampp, retrofit

I'm using xammp to test my backend scripting and I just need to `get` some JSON with retrofit. I have tried following tutorials online but to no avail. I get the error code

```
    java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:80
```

Whether I'm using localhost as the baseURL or the Ip address of localhost/xammp server or Whether I explicitly use the port or not, I get this error message or something like stated above. ***edit***: upon closer inspection of the error log it also says:

```
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

and

```
     Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /127.0.0.1 (port 80) from /127.0.0.1 (port 58156) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

could this have anything to do with it?

my full jsontest.php

```
{
    "resoponse": {
        "check": "ahhhhhhhh"
    },
    "Mlist": [{
            "text1": "text1a",
            "text2": "text2a",
            "text3": "text3a"
        },
        {
            "text1": "text1b",
            "text2": "text2b",
            "text3": "text3b"
        },
        {
            "text1": "text1c",
            "text2": "text2c",
            "text3": "text3c"
        }
    ]
}
```

simple api.kt

```
interface SimpleApi {
    @GET("jsontest.php")
    suspend fun phonehome(): Phone
}
```

main fragment.kt

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false)
        mUserViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ViewModel::class.java)

            //other code

            TestGet()

        return view
    }
val BASE_URL = "http://127.0.0.1/"
    private fun TestGet() {

        val api = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
                .create(SimpleApi::class.java)

        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
          // doing stuff with response
        }
}
```

if you could point me in the right direction I would be very thankful

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your server running on the same device as your Android app? Only then you can use localhost/127.0.0.1.

Comment: yes the emulator is running on the device as my xammp server

Comment: Yes? Please reread my comment. I asked where the server was running. Not the emulator. Then localhost/127.0.01 for your app is the emulator. But your server does not run on the emulator. Hence no connection in this way.

Comment: really? ok, how do I get my xammp stack working in conjunction with my android emulator?

Comment: Use ip 10.0.2.2 for that.

Comment: hot damn it worked! thank you, brother. do you mind making the solution an answer so I can give it the green check mark?

Comment: Well.. i already posted this answer...that comment is included of course. Everybody will understand as everybody can read.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server on port 80? By default its on 8000 or 8080, if that is the case your URL (BASE_URL) would look like this: http://127.0.0.1:xxxx/, xxxx being your port number, also check your IP address and make sure you can access the URL from outside the machine.

Comment: so upon closer inspection of the error logs it also says: `     Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1 (port 80) from /127.0.0.1 (port 58160) after 10000ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
`

Comment: any yes I can connect to localhost with just 127.0.0.1:80 in my web browser.

Comment: Webbrowser of Android device?

Comment: it works in my computers web browser but not the web browser of the android emulator

Comment: Indeed. As localhost/127.0.0.1 is not usable then. And now you know why.